# How to import MBTiles into TileMill?

Tags: mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles

I know that TileMill can export MBTiles data,also it can import XML, SQLite and POSTGis data as a Layer's datasources. I want to import MBTiles data into TileMill as a Layer's data source. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't import raster tiles, MBTiles or otherwise, into TileMill. It's meant just for source data to be rendered *into* tiles.

What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Is this still not possible? What I want is to render thumbnails of GPX tracks using tilemill...